# Attaching pdf document from named Excel range into Outlook mail

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, outlook, attachment

I am trying to attach a pdf file within a drive location into a mail. I think it is something basic I am missing on the named ranges.

The code breaks in the `.Attachments.Add` line.

```
Sub Mail()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range
Dim mainfont As String
Dim headerfont As String
Dim subheaderfont As String
Dim closemain As String
Dim closeheader As String
Dim closesubheader As String

Dim Ash As Worksheet

Set Ash = ActiveSheet
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
OutApp.Session.Logon

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

'construct email
With OutMail
    .To = Range("To").Value
    .cc = Range("Cc").Value
    .Subject = Range("Subject").Value
    .Attachments.Add ("FilePathYTD.pdf")
    .Display
End With
 
End Sub
```

Comment: *"The code breaks in the `.Attachments.Add` line"* - does it give any specific error message?

Comment: The error code states to verify the path and file name are correct

Answer (score 1):

From the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.add):

> `expression.Add (Source, Type, Position, DisplayName)`
>   Source | Required | Variant | The source of the attachment. This can be a file (represented by the **full file system path** with a file name) or an Outlook item that constitutes the attachment.
>   <sub><sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup></sub>

`"FilePathYTD.pdf"` is not a full file system path.  `"C:\Users\codingroadman53\Documents\FilePathYTD.pdf"` or `ThisWorkbook.Path & "\FilePathYTD.pdf"` are.

In response to comments: If your Full File System Path is being stored in a Named Range called "FilePathYTD", then you need to address it in the same way that you have for `.Subject`:

```
.Attachments.Add Range("FilePathYTD").Value
```

Comment: Yes I understand however the file system path is dynamic and I have named the range "FilePathYTD" to reference the file I am trying to attach. Therefore, I was hoping this would work but it doesn't. The code works if I put in the full file system path but that would not make it dynamic

Comment: @codingroadman53 In that case, you need `Range("FilePathYTD").Value`, just like you did for `.Subject` - you are currently passing it a `String`, not a cell reference.

Comment: Thank you I have managed to do it now but I had to change the named cell reference to include .pdf. Wondering if I could of done this in the code directly because when I put ("FilePathYTD.pdf").Value it doesn't work

Comment: @codingroadman53 You can't have dots or spaces in Range Names.  You *could* use `Range("FilePathYTD").Value & ".pdf"` to concatenate the file extension